# C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe" did not succeed

Tags: texify

I have installed MikTex on a new laptop but cant get it to compile "pdfLaTex+MakeIndex+BibTex"

I keep getting the error "Sorry, but "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe" did not succeed.".

I have tried several reinstallations and updates but with no success.
the log file gives the following messages

"2016-10-19 17:48:47,137+0100 INFO  texify - running 'initexmf --enable-installer --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2016-10-24 10:21:21,933+0100 INFO  texify - running 'initexmf --enable-installer --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2016-10-24 10:28:02,415+0100 INFO  texify - running 'initexmf --enable-installer --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database"

Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't use texify, run the tools individually -- then you have a chance to get better error messages.

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same problem... What do you mean run the tools individually? (I'm using teXworks). Apologies for the "timing"